# Intuition on ds v. dA in Stokes type problems

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm slowly making my way through better understanding of Stokes Theorem-type problems. I struggle with two issues, the intuition about which I'm lacking.

First, what does it mean to integrate the curl over the surface? Is this the same thing as the flux, which I usually think of as the amount of "flow" over the surface? That's confusing to me.

Second, it is usually stated that Stokes relates the surface integral of curl dot dS (over S) to the double integral of the force dot dr (over C, the contour) as in the following:

[image]

When you see a model solution, as in the following, you will see that, to calculate the right side of this equation, dS is transformed into the cross product of the partial derivatives times dA.

Why is that? dS represents the infinitesmally small surface area. Why does that become the cross of the partials times dA? Doesn't make sense to me.

Here's an example, where you can see this in action.

[image]

Comment: thru infinitesimals is a real trouble to grasp, what you need is a little more of linear algebra and the language of **differential forms** to advanced beyond of those early years of the infamous "vector analysis" stuff

Comment: This is perhaps a silly remark, but I wouldn't be too surprised if that thing with the cross product of the partials times dA is actually *explained* somewhere near Equation 6.19 in whatever source that picture is taken from. Have you tried looking there? (It has to do with the fact that the length of the cross product equals the area of the parallelogram spanned by the vectors.)

Comment: Yes, most assuredly it is explained in the text, but see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parametrize a surface by $\mathbf r(u,v)$, the parallelogram spanned by $\dfrac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}$ and $\dfrac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}$ has area $$\left\|\dfrac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times\dfrac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}\right\|.$$
The cross product itself is a (non-normalized) normal vector and this area becomes the "fudge factor" (like the $r$ in $r\,dr\,d\theta$) that tells you how to relate area in the $uv$-plane to area on the surface. After that, it's just
\begin{align*}
\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf n\,dS &= \left(\mathbf F\cdot\frac{\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}}{\left\|\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}\right\|}\right)\left\|\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}\right\|du\,dv \\
&=\mathbf F\cdot \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}\right) du\,dv.
\end{align*}

Comment: And what does it mean to integrate the curl, as I ask in my first query above? That doesn't make sense. Thanks for your help. I enjoy your videos, and will make my way through more of them.

Comment: Yes, you're finding the flux of the curl. The curl measures to what extent the force fails to be conservative, so you're adding up these non-conservative contributions across the surface to find the net work done by the force along the boundary. If you believe in Green's Theorem, it's just a minor generalization to curvy surfaces. Indeed, you can prove Stokes's from Green's Theorem if you have the parametrization on a rectangle, say, and just "pull everything back" to the rectangle.

Comment: Helpful! Many thanks. I've not see a clear explanation like you have in sentences 1 and 2 above. Much obliged.